# neo4j cypher suggestion based on common relation rating

Tags: neo4j, cypher

**Scenario:**
[graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsJRv.jpg)
John doe has rated 2 ingredients, 2 of those ingredients happen to belong to a soup recipe, and only 1 to pizza. The query should return the soup recipe because the avg of those ingredient ratings is > 5

**What I have:**
I started with below query:

> MATCH (:Subject {ref:
>   1})-[ir:INGREDIENT_RATING]->(:Ingredient)<-[:HAS_INGREDIENT]-(r:Recipe)
>   WHERE ir.value > 5 return r;

**What I would like to happen:**
This returns recipes where an ingredient has a rating above 5, but this does not take into account that other ingredients of that recipe could have lower ratings given by that user.

So I have to expand on above query but I'm a bit clueless where to start.

Thanks in advance,

**Update 1:**
Based on @InverseFalcon I came up with this, which gives me the results I expect:

> MATCH (:Subject {ref: '1'})-[ir:INGREDIENT_RATING]->(i:Ingredient)-[:HAS_INGREDIENT]-(r:Recipe)-[:KITCHEN]->(k:Kitchen)
>   MATCH (r)-[HAS_INGREDIENT]-(in:Ingredient)
>   WITH r, k, in, sum(ir.value) AS sum
>   WHERE sum > 10
>   RETURN DISTINCT r, collect(DISTINCT in) AS ingredients, k AS kitchen, sum
>   ORDER BY sum DESC

The second match is because without it, it only returns ingredients with a rating, I need all of them.

There is only one oddity and that is I get a duplicate result even tough I use distinct on r.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Please provide some examples of data and what you'd expect returned.

Comment: @betseyb I updated the scenario with an image and a better description. Hopefully it is better to understand what i try to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need the `avg()` aggregation function to take the average of multiple values. Does this work for you?

```
MATCH (:Subject {ref: 1})-[ir:INGREDIENT_RATING]->(:Ingredient)<-[:HAS_INGREDIENT]-(r:Recipe) 
WITH r, avg(ir.value) as avg
WHERE avg > 5 
RETURN r;
```

Comment: your suggestion pointed me to the right direction and was able to construct a query based on that which gave me the results I expected. I updated my post accordingly. Only, now I get a duplicate node of r, even when I use DISTINCT.

Comment: That's odd. Are your rows exactly the same? If so, you may want to check if there might actually be a duplicate recipe node in your graph.

Comment: Found it, I forgot that a recipe can have multiple kitchens, so a collect on the kitchen solved is.